# What is the solr dynamic field one should use for a large base64 string?

Tags: solr

What is the best solr dynamic field type to use for a long base64 string?

In my case, I am wanting a solr field with a base64 representation of an image. We use dynamic fields in schema so I'm looking for the right one to use.

I was going to use `_txt` but am really unsure of my choice here.

What is the best choice of dynamic field to use for long base64 strings?

Note: I am referring to the default built-in dynamic field mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binary field is the best bet otherwise.

You want a non-analyzed field that just stores the data - so using something that maps to the `string` type is a good choice. Depending on *which* schema you're using, they might be mapped to `*_s` as a dynamic field entry.

You do not want to use any text field, as they're analyzed and split into separate tokens. You also want to set `stored="true" indexed="false"` and probably disable docValues - this field isn't going to be used for anything other than retrieval.

I don't think there's any "built-in" dynamic field mappings any longer, as most examples have their own definitions.

Comment: does the default dynamic `_s` typically have a max length though? i seem to remember some sort of length restriction

Comment: Yes, a single token can not exceed about 32kb.

Comment: ok i think the answer is - none of the typical "dynamicField" that come with a standard solr will work. You need to add a "binary" field.

Comment: Example: `<dynamicField indexed="false" name="*_bin" stored="true" type="binary"/>`

Comment: Agreed, a binary field is your best bet.

Comment: just a note on the 'large' param that might be useful here: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/defining-fields.html